# Process an array of sequential boolean values

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Hard to set a title and a description for this one, but you'll get it when u read the code and comments, hopefully. If you guys got better idea please edit.

How can i get, in `javascript`, the timestamp sum difference between each `true` and `false` for each day for this particular example?

As a general rule for the array:  is it always loops true - false.

My real data is a bit more complex, but i just can't seem to get the thinking right, even for this simplified example.

Can be reduce, can be a for loop, anything. Thank you!

```
const data = [
    { day: 'today', timestamp: 11, value: true },
    { day: 'today', timestamp: 13, value: false }, //here should be 13-11
    { day: 'today', timestamp: 14, value: true },
    { day: 'today', timestamp: 17, value: false }, //here should be 17-14
    //the sum for today should be 5 (13-11 + 17-14)
    { day: 'tomorrow', timestamp: 9, value: true },
    { day: 'tomorrow', timestamp: 11, value: false }, //here should be 11-9
    { day: 'tomorrow', timestamp: 11, value: true },
    { day: 'tomorrow', timestamp: 16, value: false } //here should be 16-11 
    //the sum for today should be 7 (11-9 + 16-11)
]
```

Comment: What does your expected output look like?  What have you tried?

Comment: I'm looking for the sum for each day calculated from the difference between each true - false. Think of it like turning a light on and off and you want to know how long has the light been on and calculate the sum for each day.

Comment: The concept makes sense, but what does that look like in a data structure?

Comment: It has a timestamp and a true or false value for each action, just like the example. Sorry about the description again. I tried to make the example look more easy to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple reduce would make the job: just add the 'false' values which are bigger, and remove from the sum the 'true' values and you got it ;)

```js
const data = [
    { day: 'today', timestamp: 11, value: true },
    { day: 'today', timestamp: 13, value: false }, //here should be 13-11
    { day: 'today', timestamp: 14, value: true },
    { day: 'today', timestamp: 17, value: false }, //here should be 17-14
    //the sum for today should be 5 (13-11 + 17-14)
    { day: 'tomorrow', timestamp: 9, value: true },
    { day: 'tomorrow', timestamp: 11, value: false }, //here should be 11-9
    { day: 'tomorrow', timestamp: 11, value: true },
    { day: 'tomorrow', timestamp: 16, value: false } //here should be 16-11 
    //the sum for today should be 7 (11-9 + 16-11)
];

const result = data.reduce((acc, elt) => {
  if(!acc[elt.day]) acc[elt.day] = 0;
  if(!elt.value) {
    acc[elt.day] += elt.timestamp;
  } else {
    acc[elt.day] -= elt.timestamp;
  }
  return acc;
},{});
console.log(result);
```

Do not forget to init each day to 0 in the accumulator!
Hoping this will help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `reduce` easily

```js
const data = [
    { day: 'today', timestamp: 11, value: true },
    { day: 'today', timestamp: 13, value: false },
    { day: 'today', timestamp: 14, value: true },
    { day: 'today', timestamp: 17, value: false },
    { day: 'tomorrow', timestamp: 9, value: true },
    { day: 'tomorrow', timestamp: 11, value: false }, 
    { day: 'tomorrow', timestamp: 11, value: true },
    { day: 'tomorrow', timestamp: 16, value: false } 
]

const op = data.reduce((o,c)=>{
  if(o[c['day']]){
    o[c['day']]['timestamp'] += c.value ? -c.timestamp : c.timestamp;
  }  else {
    o[c['day']] = {
      'timestamp' : c.value ? -c.timestamp : c.timestamp
    }
  }
  return o;
},{})

console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a check with the last inserted object in the result set and update timestamp.

```js
const
    data = [{ day: 'today', timestamp: 11, value: true }, { day: 'today', timestamp: 13, value: false }, { day: 'today', timestamp: 14, value: true }, { day: 'today', timestamp: 17, value: false }, { day: 'tomorrow', timestamp: 9, value: true }, { day: 'tomorrow', timestamp: 11, value: false }, { day: 'tomorrow', timestamp: 11, value: true }, { day: 'tomorrow', timestamp: 16, value: false }],
    result = data.reduce((r, { day, timestamp, value }) => {
        var last = r[r.length - 1];
        if (!last || last.day !== day) {
            r.push(last = { day, timestamp: 0 });
        }
        last.timestamp += value ? -timestamp : +timestamp;
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```